# JQuery hiding and unhiding elements from dropdown selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a set of small tables each with a unique ID and a class that loads them up as display none.

I then need a selector where a visitor can select a country and the relevant table containing the matching shipping method will have the hidden class removed.

I've kind of got the basics thrashed out but the jQuery for this has halted me in my path.

```js
        $(function(){
          // bind change event to select
          $('#country_selector').on('change', function () {
              var shippingMethod = $(this).val(); // get selected value
              if (shippingMethod) { // 
                  
              }
              return false;
          });
        });
```

```css
table.load-hidden{

display:none;
}
```

```html
<select id="country_selector">
  <option value="" selected="selected">Select your Country</option>
  <option value="australia-post-ground-parcel">Australia</option>
  <option value="usps-first-class-mail-international">Canada</option>
  <option value="australia-post-pack-and-track-international-parcel">New Zealand</option>
  <option value="usps-priority-mail-plus-signature">United States</option>
</select>


<table id="usps-priority-mail-plus-signature" class="load-hidden">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="first odd">
      <th class="label">Shipping Method</th>
      <td class="data">USPS Priority Mail + Signature Required</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even">
      <th class="label">Estimated Delivery Time</th>
      <td class="data">3 to 5 working days</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
      <th class="label">Customs &amp; Import Fees</th>
      <td class="data">Ground Shipped, No fees apply</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even">
      <th class="label">Shipped From</th>
      <td class="data">United States, Philadelphia Depot</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>






<table id="usps-first-class-mail-international" class="load-hidden">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="first odd">
      <th class="label">Shipping Method</th>
      <td class="data">USPS First-Class Mail International</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even">
      <th class="label">Estimated Delivery Time</th>
      <td class="data">10 to 15 working days</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
      <th class="label">Customs &amp; Import Fees</th>
      <td class="data">Customs &amp; import fees may apply</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even">
      <th class="label">Shipped From</th>
      <td class="data">United States, Philadelphia Depot</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>










<table id="australia-post-ground-parcel" class="load-hidden">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="first odd">
      <th class="label">Shipping Method</th>
      <td class="data">Australia Post Ground Parcel</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even">
      <th class="label">Estimated Delivery Time</th>
      <td class="data">3 to 5 working days</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
      <th class="label">Customs &amp; Import Fees</th>
      <td class="data">Ground Shipped, No fees apply</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even">
      <th class="label">Shipped From</th>
      <td class="data">Australia, Sydney Depot</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table id="australia-post-pack-and-track-international-parcel" class="load-hidden">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="first odd">
      <th class="label">Shipping Method</th>
      <td class="data">Australia Post Pack and Track International Parcel</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even">
      <th class="label">Estimated Delivery Time</th>
      <td class="data">10 to 15 working days</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
      <th class="label">Customs &amp; Import Fees</th>
      <td class="data">Customs &amp; import fees may apply</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even">
      <th class="label">Shipped From</th>
      <td class="data">Australia, Sydney Depot</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>










<table id="royal-mail-first-class-packet-signed-for" class="load-hidden">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="first odd">
      <th class="label">Shipping Method</th>
      <td class="data">Royal Mail First Class Packet Signed For</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even">
      <th class="label">Estimated Delivery Time</th>
      <td class="data">10 to 15 working days</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
      <th class="label">Customs &amp; Import Fees</th>
      <td class="data">Ground Shipped, No fees apply</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even">
      <th class="label">Shipped From</th>
      <td class="data">United Kingdom, London Depot</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table id="royal-mail-international-standard" class="load-hidden">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="first odd">
      <th class="label">Shipping Method</th>
      <td class="data">Royal Mail International Standard</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even">
      <th class="label">Estimated Delivery Time</th>
      <td class="data">10 to 15 working days</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
      <th class="label">Customs &amp; Import Fees</th>
      <td class="data"><b>EU based Customers:</b> No Customs Fees apply
        <br /><b>Customers Outside EU:</b> Customs &amp; import fees may apply
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even">
      <th class="label">Shipped From</th>
      <td class="data">United Kingdom, London Depot</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table id="royal-mail-international-tracked" class="load-hidden">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="first odd">
      <th class="label">Shipping Method</th>
      <td class="data">Royal Mail International Tracked</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even">
      <th class="label">Estimated Delivery Time</th>
      <td class="data">10 to 15 working days</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
      <th class="label">Customs &amp; Import Fees</th>
      <td class="data"><b>EU based Customers:</b> No Customs Fees apply
        <br /><b>Customers Outside EU:</b> Customs &amp; import fees may apply
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even">
      <th class="label">Shipped From</th>
      <td class="data">United Kingdom, London Depot</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table id="royal-mail-international-signed-for" class="load-hidden">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="first odd">
      <th class="label">Shipping Method</th>
      <td class="data">Royal Mail International Signed For</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even">
      <th class="label">Estimated Delivery Time</th>
      <td class="data">10 to 15 working days</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
      <th class="label">Customs &amp; Import Fees</th>
      <td class="data"><b>EU based Customers:</b> No Customs Fees apply
        <br /><b>Customers Outside EU:</b> Customs &amp; import fees may apply
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even">
      <th class="label">Shipped From</th>
      <td class="data">United Kingdom, London Depot</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be straight forward as the option values match the ID's

```
$(function() {
    $('#country_selector').on('change', function() {
        $('.load-hidden').hide();
        $('#' + this.value).show();
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/gnso1mov/)

Comment: Works a treat, I was well over thinking it. Many thanks.